# MicrosoftGraph API list messages by specific categories

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I have tried the $filter and $search directives with no luck.

Example queries that have failed:

- GET .../v1/users/me/messages?$filter=categories in 'Yellow'
- GET .../messages?$filter=any(categories:categories eq 'Yellow')
- GET .../messages?$search="categories:Yellow"

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters

Comment: Hi, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the below query to filter the categories which have a value 'Yellow'.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=categories/any(c:c eq 'Yellow')
```

Here 'Yellow' is the category which I added as a custom category.

If you are using the builtin categories like 'Blue category' or 'Yellow category' you need to use the exact string to filter it.

Comment: Thank you Shiva. Now to extend this slightly further, how would i go about using the  "in" directive?
Failed Tries:
- ...?$filter=categories/any(c:c in 'Yellow' or 'Pink')
- ...?$filter=categories/any(c:c in 'Yellow'/'Pink')
- ...?$filter=categories/any(c:c in 'Yellow':'Pink')

Looking at query params documentation referenced doesn't provide an example, and neither does the referenced OData v4 standard spec.

Comment: Successful, but less preferred option
...?$filter=categories/any(c:c eq 'Yellow') or categories/any(c:c eq 'Pink')

Comment: Actually, 'in' is not supported yet on MS Graph. You can raise a feature request or support similar ones in the [Microsoft Graph Feedback Forum](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#filter-parameter suggests that it is supported. Is this a case where a feature was de-scoped?

Comment: In the same document you can see "Support for $filter operators varies across Microsoft Graph APIs." since this is /messages endpoint it doesn't have support for "in" on it looks like.